# (VBA) Exception handling for dashes (-), need to turn to 0's

Tags: vba

Some of the values found in Sheet74 are dashes (-). If the values are dashes, they should be 0's.

```
    Sheet8.Range("O12").Value = Sheet74.Range("D3")
    Sheet8.Range("o13").Value = Sheet74.Range("D4")
    Sheet8.Range("o17").Value = Sheet74.Range("d5") + Sheet74.Range("d6") + Sheet74.Range("d7")
    Sheet8.Range("o19").Value = Sheet74.Range("d9")
    Sheet8.Range("o20").Value = Sheet74.Range("d10")
```

Rather than testing the condition for each line, should I write a subroutine? something like this:

```
sub test(a as long, optional b as long, optional c as long) 
'testing condition here'
'copies values, and 0's if dash is found 
end sub
```

EDIT::

```
Function fixDash(rng As Range) As Long
If IsNumeric(rng.Value) Then
   fixDash = rng.Value
Else
    fixDash = 0
End Function
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 3):

you could use `Replace()`:

```
Sheet8.Range("O12").Value = Replace(Sheet74.Range("D3"),"-","0")
```

Comment: If the value was -123 that would change to 0123 ... Depending on how messy the data is might want to be careful about that.

Comment: @NikT Sheet8.Range("o17").Value = Sheet74.Range("d5") + Sheet74.Range("d6") + Sheet74.Range("d7"). When I use Ryan's replace method, that line becomes 0 0 0. Is there another solution so that it's 0 and not 0 0 0?

Comment: are you replacing each occurrence?  e.g. `Replace(Sheet74.Range("d5"),"-","0") + Replace(Sheet74.Range("d6"),"-","0") + Replace(Sheet74.Range("d7"),"-","0")`

Comment: Yes I am, the result is 0 0 0

Comment: @excelmonkey93 Cast each `Replace` statement as an integer like this: `CInt(Replace(Sheet74.Range("d5"),"-","0")) + CInt(Replace(Sheet74.Range("d6"),"-","0")) + CInt(Replace(Sheet74.Range("d7"),"-","0"))` The `+` character either concatenates strings or adds numbers depending on the data type. If you force the data to be Integers, the plus will add the zeros to be 1 zero.

Comment: @tim how would i account for negative numbers? If negative, I want to keep the negative value. please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

As a function, you could do something like

```
Function FixDashes(inp As String) As String
     FixDashes = Replace(inp, "-", "0")
End Function
```

Then you'd end up with

```
Sheet8.Range("o13").Value = FixDashes(Sheet74.Range("D4"))
Sheet8.Range("o17").Value = FixDashed(Sheet74.Range("d5") + Sheet74.Range("d6") + Sheet74.Range("d7"))
```

EDIT: to answer the add-on question from comments, transform "0 0 0" into "0" by making the function like this:

```
Function FixDashes(inp As String) As String
    Dim tmp As String
    tmp = Replace(inp, "-", "0")
    Do While InStr(tmp, "0 0") > 0
        tmp = Replace(tmp, "0 0", "0")
    Loop
    FixDashes = tmp
End Function
```

Comment: when I use the replace method, it displays as 0 0 0. I would like it to sum the 0's. How do I change it so that it sums up?

Comment: I went ahead with the conversion to long values, thank you though.